# Consume Rabbitt MQ via CLI (Linux Terminal)

Tags: linux, sockets, rabbitmq, command-line-interface, message-queue

I have published a message with the command:

```
rabbitmqadmin publish exchange=topic.exchange routing_key=key-doku payload='wecew'
```

and then how to consume it and get payload content via cli (linux terminal) ?

Expect:
example command consume rabbitmq message

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` command. You need to specify the queue name like:

```
 rabbitmqadmin get queue=keydokuQ
```